# lampp newest virtual host "Access forbidden"

Tags: apache, xampp, virtualhost, lamp, centos6

I have lampp running on a CentOS 6 box with a few virtual host running, all my virtual hosts are running fine, except for the one I added most recently (abacusnurseryschool.com).

I have not got a clue why this is the only virtual host that is not working. My root lampp/htdocs directory is forbidden, however all my other directorys accesible by my virual hosts are (i.e. samvella.co.uk)

hear is a copy of my httpd-vhost.conf

```
    # Virtual Hosts
#
# Required modules: mod_log_config

# If you want to maintain multiple domains/hostnames on your
# machine you can setup VirtualHost containers for them. Most configurations
# use only name-based virtual hosts so the server doesn't need to worry about
# IP addresses. This is indicated by the asterisks in the directives below.
#
# Please see the documentation at 
# <URL:http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/>
# for further details before you try to setup virtual hosts.
#
# You may use the command line option '-S' to verify your virtual host
# configuration.

#
# VirtualHost example:
# Almost any Apache directive may go into a VirtualHost container.
# The first VirtualHost section is used for all requests that do not
# match a ServerName or ServerAlias in any <VirtualHost> block.
#
<VirtualHost *:80>
     DocumentRoot “/opt/lampp/htdocs/abacus/“
     ServerName abacusnurseryschool.com
     ServerAlias www.abacusnurseryschool.com
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
     DocumentRoot “/opt/lampp/htdocs/betltc/“
     ServerName betltc.co.uk
     ServerAlias www.betltc.co.uk
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
     DocumentRoot “/opt/lampp/htdocs/valeouse/“
     ServerName valeouse.co.uk 
     ServerAlias www.valeouse.co.uk
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
     DocumentRoot “/opt/lampp/htdocs/valeouse/“
     ServerName samvella.co.uk
     ServerAlias www.samvella.co.uk
</VirtualHost>
```

all the virtual hosts are working apart from abacusnurseryschool.com, not sure why, all the other virtual hosts were set a while ago so I may have also altered other files? but I cannot think what else needs changing.

Regards,
Sam

Answer (score 0):

Simple, but a common fix. Reload Apache.

```
# sudo /etc/init.d/httpd reload
```

Comment: tried this (but with sudo /opt/lampp/lampp reload (because I a am using lampp stack) and still nothing.

Comment: Did you try without the `sudo` if you are the root?

Comment: Yes, Have tried with both, have also tried restarting,  stoping and then starting lampp ...

Comment: What are your sites listed when you run `# ls -l /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/`?

Comment: I dont have that directory because I am running lamp (and i have searched for a `sites-enabled` folder using the  `find . -name sites-enabled` however i am not sure if this will work because it is a directory ... however i think this still works.

Comment: Well your code states that it's running Apache 2.4  which uses enabled-sites. But it could just be a permissions issue, `# cd /opt/lampp` then `# sudo chmod 777 -R htdocs`

Comment: Have also tried doing this, still nothing, may try a fresh install of lampp? although I cannot really see that helping anything...